# Built-in rule applied instead of specific one in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using these two makefiles :

```
$ cat Makefile
#-- TARGET definition :
TARGET_TYPE=exe#one of : exe, lib, default to exe
TARGET=test_bmpfile_save
#-- libs definition :
LIBS=libbmpfile#list of libs which must be recompiled by this Makefile
STDLIBS=libm#list of list which must be include to compile
#-- definitions for each lib from $(LIBS):
bmpfile_DIR=..#mandatory, directory containing both library and its Makefile.
bmpfile_INC=..#optionnal, default to lib_DIR : dirname containing lib's headers files.
#-- srcs definition :
SRCS=bmpfile_save.c
SRCS_DIRS=
SRCS_INCS=.#
#-- IMPORTANT :
GEN_MAKEFILE_PATH=../../../fw/
#
#---- dont change anything after this
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

include $(GEN_MAKEFILE_PATH)genMakefile
```

and :

```
$ cat ../../../fw/genMakefile 
RTARGET_TYPE=$(if $(TARGET_TYPE),$(TARGET_TYPE),exe)
LIBS_FPATHS=$(foreach lib,$(LIBS:lib%=%),$($(lib)_DIR)/lib$(lib).a)
LIBS_DIRS=$(foreach lib,$(LIBS:lib%=%),$($(lib)_DIR))
LDLIBS=$(LIBS_DIRS:%=-L%) $(LIBS:lib%=-l%) $(STDLIBS:lib%=-l%)
LIBS_INCS=$(foreach lib,$(LIBS:lib%=%),$(if $($(lib)_INC),$($(lib)_INC),$($(lib)_DIR)))
IFLAGS=$(SRCS_INCS:%=-I%) $(LIBS_INCS:%=-I%)
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror $(IFLAGS)
empty=
space=$(empty) $(empty)
VPATH=$(subst $(space),:,$(SRCS_DIRS))
vpath lib%.a $(subst $(space),:,$(LIBS_DIRS))

.PHONY:all
all:$(TARGET)

ifeq ($(RTARGET_TYPE),exe)
$(TARGET):$(LIBS:%=%.a) $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)  -o $@ $(LDLIBS)#This recipe is not applied

else
$(TARGET): $(LIBS:%=%.a) $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
        ar -rc $@ $(LIBS_FPATHS) $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
        ranlib $@
endif

ifneq ($(LIBS),)
lib%.a:
        $(MAKE) -C $($*_DIR)
endif

.PHONY:$(LIBS:%=%.fclean)
lib%.fclean:
        $(MAKE) -C $($*_DIR) fclean

.PHONY:clean
clean:
        rm -f $(wildcard *.o)

.PHONY: fclean
fclean:$(LIBS:%=%.fclean) clean
        rm -f $(TARGET)

.PHONY:re
re:fclean $(TARGET)
```

And when i `make` the first, i expect the `$(TARGET)` rule to be applied...
This is the output then :

```
$ make
cc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I. -I..    bmpfile_save.c  -L.. -lbmpfile -lm -o bmpfile_save
../libbmpfile.a(bmpfile_save.o): In function `write_headers':
/home/david/42Projects/minirt/srcs/bmpfile/bmpfile_save.c:17: undefined reference to `t_sys_init'
/home/david/42Projects/minirt/srcs/bmpfile/bmpfile_save.c:21: undefined reference to `ft_bzero'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'bmpfile_save' failed
make: *** [bmpfile_save] Error 1
```

Instead, make seems to apply [this built-in rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#index-_002eo-1) (it is the only one i found **almost** applyable here) despite the fact that the name of executable does not match any of the .o's filename...
I can't understand why this rule seems to be applied (if it is). What do I miss ?

Comment: Please show the incorrect output that you see when writing a question.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this:

```
$(TARGET):$(LIBS:%=%.a) $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)
        this rule is not used... at all ^^
```

What is really in your makefile here?  It can't be exactly as above because that's a syntax error.

Comment: In fact, i wrote a recipe in the real make file, i wrote this here to mark the rule. But you are right i should just have commented it.

Comment: Why not write the recipe in your question as well?  It makes a _HUGE_ difference whether this target has a recipe or not.  Basically, if this rule does have a recipe, and there's nothing "unusual" about the value of TARGET (which we might be able to see if you had included the output of the make command), then I don't see any way that you can get the behavior you say you have where a built-in rule is used to build this target.  You've declared an explicit rule for that target and so that's it: make will never try to look up any implicit rule, much less a built-in rule.

Comment: Yes as i said above, i thought it was clever to write this but it was not.
I was editing it, with output from ``make`` too.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, the built-in rule called is for the .o files in the prerequisite... sorry for this stupid question.